# Eslint wont work because of eslint plugin error?

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

I can't seem to get my eslint to work.

I have the eslint extenstion on vscode. I created a new node project and npm installed eslint as a dev dependency. I chose the Air-BNB style and then went to check if it worked. Whenever I open a file I get a notification saying there is an error with eslint.

Vscode notification [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH2DU.png)

ESlint stack trace [error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2ONV.png)

Some things I did:

- I installed eslint locally.
- At one point I found out that I had eslint installed globally so I
  removed it and stuck with the local install per project basis.
- Ive disabled and enabled vscode eslint (Extension ESlint 2.1.8).

**My Config File:**

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es2020: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb-base',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 11,
  },
  rules: {
  },
};
```

**Here are my dev dependencies:**

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.7.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-require": "0.0.1"
  }
```

Comment: Switch off the VSCode linter and try again. And please post your eslint config.

Comment: @EliseChant I've tried switching it on and off, still same issue

Comment: Ok I solved the issue but I don't know why or how. I was attempting to uninstall and reinstall everything and when I went I uninstalled eslint it started working... so now I don't have eslint as one of my dev dependencies

Answer (score 1):

The problem is right their in the error message, you have two different versions of `eslint-plugin-import` in your node-modules tree. You just need to make sure you only have one version.

I expect you tried to add a newer version than the one used by CRA.